# SQL Выборка записей из одной и другой таблицы по одному условию

Tags: mysql

Возникла проблема с составлением запроса mysql.

Есть 2 таблицы: в обеих всего 2 поля id и title. Так вот, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать выборку записей с условием LIKE по названию из обеих таблиц.

Comment: Можно же просто сделать два запроса. Не уверен что это "профессилонально", но за то удобно и понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю вам поможет оператор UNION ALL.